# ImportError: cannot import name 'FFmpegPCMaudio' from 'discord'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

So my code is working fine on my computer but i want to heberge it on my rpi4 with ubuntu server LTS 20.04 on it and my bot cant play the file :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from discord import FFmpegPCMaudio
ImportError: cannot import name 'FFmpegPCMaudio' from 'discord' (/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/__init__.py)
```

Does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 1):

You just made an uppercase typo mistake. It has to be `FFmpegPCMAudio` instead of `FFmpegPCMaudio`.